# How to design a frame for Ipad covering the half of the screen by height using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout

I want to cover half of the  screen of ipad using a popup ,and i want to design a frame for the same.
desired result is achieved by using the following code for iphone,but it is not working in case of ipad.

```
 let frame = CGRect(x: self.moreButton.frame.origin.x + self.stackOfButtons.frame.width / 2 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.stackOfButtons.frame.origin.x, width: self.moreButton.frame.width, height: self.moreButton.frame.height)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it with auto layout, declare your view:

```
let dummyView = UIView()
```

in viewDidLoad set dummyView, add it and set constraints::

```
dummyView.backgroundColor = .red
dummyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(dummyView)
dummyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

The red view is the result

[image]

If you want to cover from top change constraints like this:

```
view.addSubview(dummyView)
dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
dummyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

This is the result

[image]